# Javascript point to an object property

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
   elements = new Array(
       {opinions: 'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions'}, // function to call and API endpoint, php/endpoint.php
       {top3positive: 'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3positive'}, // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
       {top3negative: 'p31/php/endpoint.php?get=top3negative'} // function to call andAPI endpoint, php/endpoint.php
        );
```

I am trying to get value. The simple thing would be for example: `elements[0].opinions`will correctly return `p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions`
The fact is that I need to get the same info without knowing directly the values.

So I am doing the following:

```
function getEndPoint(element) {
    for (index in elements) {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elements[index]) == element) {
            console.log(eval(elements[index]. element));
        }
    }
}
```

`element` for example stands for opinions.
When I do `console.log(eval(elements[index]. element));` it is not correctly returning `p31/php/endpoint.php?get=opinions` but returns undefined. 
I also tried to use `eval()` in order to evaluate `element` from a string to runnable code, but nothing.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Avoid using `eval` if possible.

Comment: This is not a very well designed way of storing those urls. Can you change it? Also, you should never use a `for..in` loop on arrays... use a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
elements[index][element]
```

But is this not simply what you want?

```
elements[element]
```

Also, use === instead of ==...

Comment: Glad I could help! An accept of the answer is greatly appreciated.